# realurl config for tt_news in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, realurl, tt-news

For TYPO3 6.2 I cannot manage to have real url setup for `tt_news`. I use bootstrap package 6.2.8 , realurl 1.12.8 and tt_news 3.6.0.
I get url :

```
.../blog/articol.html?tx_ttnews[tt_news]=11&cHash=d92d53eafcb2e8c331829520e053c3c7
```

and should be :

```
.../blog/articol/title/
```

I try to add configuration used in version 4.5.32 but nothing was changed.
Any clues on how I should solve it?

Answer (score -1):

1. check path to your realurlconf.php or real_urlconf.php config file in the extension config
2. add `'noMatch' => 'bypass'` in

   'preVars' => array(
           array(
               'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                   'valueMap' => array(
                   'no_cache' => 1,
               ),
               'noMatch' => 'bypass',
           ),

also for me day was missing!

```
 array('GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[day]' ,
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',),
```